# Parse a JSON file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Coingecko API. But I just couldn't parse the data. Sample data is below. Parse each block I want to do.

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchanges

Sample code I use:

```js
$.getJSON( "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchanges", function( data ) {
 var objArray = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(objArray["0"]['id']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `data` is already a parsed JSON object. It is not required to parse it again. You may directly access as `data[0].id`

Answer (score 3):

Basically you don't need to do anything

```js
$.getJSON( "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchanges", function( data ) {
 console.log(data[0].id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks you for comment. Problem is solved.